# Recording if the person has used all response categories across all questionnaire items?

Tags: r, dplyr, count

My questionnaire got 30 items, and only 3 response categories (1, 2, and 3)
This time, I want to create a  new variable that uses records whether or not the person has used all response categories across all questionnaire items.
Let me show  you:

So if the respondents used multiple responses 1,2,3 throughout the entire questionnaire,  the new variable will show either Yes or True. If not, I want it to show No or False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option

```
df1$Use <- apply(df1[-1], 1, FUN = function(x) all(1:3 %in% x))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, Item1 = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L), Item2 = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 2L), Item3 = c(3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L), Item4 = c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), Item5 = c(3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

In `dplyr` you can use `rowwise` with `c_across` -

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
       rowwise() %>%
       mutate(Use = all(1:3 %in% c_across(starts_with('Item')))) %>%
       ungroup

df

#     ID Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4 Item5 Use  
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <lgl>
#1     1     2     1     3     2     3 TRUE 
#2     2     1     1     1     1     1 FALSE
#3     3     2     2     2     2     2 FALSE
#4     4     3     3     3     3     3 FALSE
#5     5     2     2     2     1     1 FALSE
```